# Group same dynamic HTML elements using CSS

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="group-index-1"></div>
<div class="group-index-1"></div>
<div class="group-index-2"></div>
<div class="group-index-2"></div>
```

The number in the `group-index-` class is dynamic and I could have *n* number of group indexes.

I would like to be able to style the first `<div>` in each group index. I.e. the first `<div>` with class name `group-index-1` and `group-index-2`.

I know this is easily done using JavaScript but I would prefer, if possible, to do this purely in CSS.

Comment: if you knew then you can use `nth-` tye